# Subprocess Popen can't send multiple commands, commands seems to be cut

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, ssh, subprocess

Assume the following Python code, I am trying to open an SSH connection and keep it open and send multiple commands. I know `communicate` won't work since it will close the connection, so I am using `write`, but `write` seems to cut commands with whitespaces between them.

```
class ReadOutputThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file_obj, output_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.file_obj = file_obj
        self.output_queue = output_queue
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        for line in iter(self.file_obj.readline, ''):
            self.output_queue.put(line.strip())
        self.file_obj.close()

class YourClass:
    def __init__(self, username: str, ssh_key: str, hostname: str="1.1.1.1"):
        self.ssh_session = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-T', '-i', ssh_key, '-Y', f'{username}@{hostname}'],
                                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                            universal_newlines=True, shell=False)
        self.output_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.stdout_thread = ReadOutputThread(self.ssh_session.stdout, self.output_queue)
        self.stderr_thread = ReadOutputThread(self.ssh_session.stderr, self.output_queue)
        self.stdout_thread.start()
        self.stderr_thread.start()
        self.execute_ssh_cmd(" ") # clean 
        self.ssh_session.stdin.flush()

    def execute_ssh_cmd(self, command):
        try:
            # Debug: Print the command before sending
            print(f"Executing command: {command}")

            # Send the command to the SSH session
            self.ssh_session.stdin.write(command)
            self.ssh_session.stdin.write(" \n")
            self.ssh_session.stdin.flush()  # Ensure data is sent immediately

            # Read the output from the queue
            output_lines = []
            while True:
                try:
                    line = self.output_queue.get(timeout=1)
                    if command.strip() in line.strip():  # Check if the command is part of the line
                        continue
                    output_lines.append(line)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            return output_lines
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error writing to SSH session:", e)
            return None
```

Main block:

```
ssh_key_path = ""
hostname = "1.1.1.1"
username = 'user'

your_instance = YourClass(username, ssh_key_path, hostname)
output1 = your_instance.execute_ssh_cmd('ls -l')
print("Final output 1:", output1)

output2 = your_instance.execute_ssh_cmd("pwd")
print("Final output 2:", output2)
```

Output:

```
Executing command: ls
Final output 1: [': No such file or directory']
Executing command: pwd
Final output 2: ['/root']
```

As you see, the `ls -l` command got cut.

I attempted to retype the command with whitespaces, "", '' f strings format and other string options.

Comment: I don't see in your code where `command` might be modified. I think what you post does not contain the trouble spot, but your real code does.

Comment: Also, learn to use either `fabric` (high-level, built on top of paramiko) or `paramiko` (lower-level); it will make your job easier.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `subprocess`, there is a module called Paramiko. You can install this using `pip3 install paramiko`. This module is specifically meant for handling SSH connections in Python. And using this module is very easy. Your multiple commands need to be created as a list and then you can iterate over the list to execute them one by one.

```
import paramiko as pm

# Create SSH instance
ssh = pm.SSHClient()

# Automatically add host keys without prompting
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(pm.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect to the SSH server
ssh.connect(hostname='<hostname>', username='<username>', password='<password>')

# keep the connection ON and run multiple commands
try:
    # Open a channel
    ch = ssh.invoke_shell()

    # create a list containg your commands
    cmds = ['cmd1', 'cmd2', 'cmd3']
    for x in cmds:
        # Send the command
        ch.send(x + '\n')

        # Wait for the command to finish 
        while not ch.recv_ready(): pass
            

        # Read and print the command output
        output = ch.recv(1024).decode()
        print(output)

    # Close the channel
    ch.close()
    
except: print("Error writing to SSH session:")

# Close the SSH connection
finally: ssh.close()
```

Comment: Huh? Paramiko is _not_ part of Python's standard library.

Comment: No, paramiko is not part of the Python's standard library, but is it a requirement? Only the OP can tell.

Comment: @tripleee, Thank you and I'm sorry for the wrong info. As I could use paramiko in my ubuntu 22.04, I have been thinking that it's part of python package. probably it would have been installed as a dependency for some other packages. Edited the answer now.

Comment: paramiko is problematic, i need X11 over SSH